# Google docs PDF view isn't always displayed

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, pdf

I use the google docs PDF view, and 50% of the time the PDF is not displayed. Just after you refresh it it is displaying the PDF.
I use:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/mypdf.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Any idea why? Thanks!